# Any similar concept of "undefined" in other languages?

Tags: javascript, undefined

I know undefined is not equal to null. But is there any similar concepts in the other languages like c#, C++ or java?

Comment: Nothing like `undefined` in C or C++.  Pointers can be initialized to `null` and then tested for `null`, but other types like `int` can only be a number.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no such similar concept on server side code. Because javascript is interpreted language, you can access a property even if it's not defined and return "undefined". But server side code like c#,c++,java are compiled languages, you have to define it before using. In c# 4.0, there is a dynamic key word, it's similar but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the languages you listed (C#, C++, Java) are [statically-typed languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_type-checking). In statically-typed languages you need to know the type of every expression at compile-time, so having things be "undefined" usually doesn't make sense because it would be a type error. As you already pointed out, null pointers / references are probably the closest thing you get to an "undefined" value in most statically-typed languages.

JavaScript is [dynamically-typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Dynamic_type-checking_and_runtime_type_information), and that's why it has `undefined`. If you look at other dynamically typed-languages you can find similar concepts. E.g., Python has a `None` value that has some similarities to `undefined` in JavaScript.

Comment: `None` in Python is more like `null`. On occasions when JS gives you `undefined`, e.g. accessing unassigned variable, non-existing dictionary key or object method, Python usually just throws an exception. A closer example would be `nil` in Lua that plays the role of both.

Comment: +1. Java variables either are `null`, or point to an object or primitive.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @DaoWen's examples...

Perl has an [undefined value](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-values) (often abbreviated "undef") separate from null or 0.  It can be tested for with [defined](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html), and generally indicates a runtime error occurred (when exceptions are not in use).  In a boolean context, it is considered false.  You can get it by...

- declaring, but never initializing, a variable: `my $foo;`
- returning nothing from a subroutine: `sub foo { return; }`
- explicitly setting a variable to undef: `$foo = undef;`

SQL has the NULL value.  Unlike the undefined value, it is not false.  It is a [3rd boolean state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29) neither true nor false.  This trinary logic often trips up people who may confuse NULL with false.

Answer (score 0):

javascript has unused variables and attributes default to undefined in order to help keep badly written web pages from failing completely.  Most other languages have similar features that must be used intentionally.  Statically typed languages have the added limitation that the type of the attribute or variable must be declared, which generally means that the variable may be NULL, but won't be completely undefined (it has a type).  On the other hand, most object oriented languages have the ability to look up an attribute and return it or return a specified alternate if the attribute doesn't exist on the object.  Consider:

```
class Undefined(object):
  pass

a=object()
b=getattr(a,'b',Undefined)
print b is Undefined
```

will print `True`.

Java has a similar ability but of course you have to know what the type of the attribute is if it exists, you'll see it used with reflection.  I assume there is something similar for c++, but I don't know any details.

As a side note, you can implement Undefined at the class and module level in Python with some mild black magic.  In the class's `__getattribute__` method, have it return `Undefined` if the attribute isn't in the class's attributes, and then create a subclass of `types.ModuleType` and define a `__getattribute__` on it that also returns `Undefined`, but I suggest thinking hard about that before doing it, as I can't see a case where you'd actually want any name to reference a value even if it's a typo...